# How to make Flexbox work with children when using horizontal MUI Collapse Component and TransitionGroup transitions?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-transitions

I am using MUI and have a hard time using the Collapse + TransitionGroup Component and getting the containers to expand with flex box.

```js
<Box sx={{display: 'flex', height: '100vh', width: '100vw'}}>
  <Box sx={{flex: 1}}>Content-A</Box>
  <Box sx={{flex: 1}}>Content-B</Box>
</Box>
```

This is a simple example of what I want. Both Boxes next to each other and splitting the whole page in a left side and right side. However when you introduce the Collapse Component it will break:

```js
<TransitionGroup sx={{display: 'flex', height: '100vh', width: '100vw}}>
  <Collapse orientation='horizontal'>
    <Box sx={{flex: 1}}>Content-A</Box>
  </Collapse>
  <Collapse orientation='horizontal'>
    <Box sx={{flex: 1}}>Content-B</Box>
  </Collapse>
</TransitionGroup>
```

The Collapse component is now interfering directly with the Flexbox parent-child relationship. If I look into the DOM I notice that the Collapse Component inserts 3 wrappers around the child component (root, outer, inner wrap). How do I pass the flexbox properties down to the original child?
I tried overriding the style of each of those wrapping components in the theme and giving them `display: flex, flex: 1` to force it all the way down the chain to the child but that breaks the transition and it looks super choppy.

**EDIT:**
For clarification: I need the transition group because I want a specific transition to happen. Basically I have the page split in left (A) and right (B). On an event I want (A) to transition out the screen (to the left, hence horizontal). (B) should transition to the place where (A) was and a new element (C) comes in from the right and transitions to where (B) was. Imagine it is like a Sliding Queue. Then it is rinse and repeat (B out -> C goes to where B was -> D transitions in to where C was). The problem is that using Collapse horizontal it wont flex the remaining space.

Comment: Put another box component as child of `TransitionGroup` the one in your first example and pass the collapse components from your second example in, instead of the box components in your first example

Comment: @CasperKuethe unfortunately that doesnt seem to work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that css `flex` and `<Collapse />` are not mean to be used in this manner.
`<Collapse />` itself will set css like `width:0px` that your `display:flex` will simply ignore.

## Using CSSTransition

As an alternative you can create and set the transition rules yourself using the `<CSSTransition />` component.
This is also used by the `<Collapse/>` internally.

The [docs](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) should be helpfull.

## Example

there is a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/transitiongroupexample-material-demo-forked-vtz6j?file=/demo.js)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  "slide-enter": {
    flexGrow: 0,
    width: 0,
    overflow: "hidden",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    transition: "all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms"
  },
  "slide-active-enter": {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "auto",
    overflow: "hidden",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    transition: "all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms"
  },
  "slide-done-enter": {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "auto",
    overflow: "hidden",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  },
  "slide-exit": {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "auto",
    transition: "all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms"
  },
  "slide-active-exit": {
    flexGrow: 0,
    width: 0,
    overflow: "hidden",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,
    transition: "all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms"
  },
  "slide-done-exit": {
    flexGrow: 0,
    width: 0,
    overflow: "hidden",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0
  }
});

.......
     <TransitionGroup style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {columns.map((_, i) =>
          i >= columns.length - 2 ? (
            <CSSTransition
              key={i}
              timeout={300}
              classNames={{
                appear: classes["slide-enter"],
                appearActive: classes["slide-active-enter"],
                appearDone: classes["slide-done-enter"],
                enter: classes["slide-enter"],
                enterActive: classes["slide-active-enter"],
                enterDone: classes["slide-done-enter"],
                exit: classes["slide-exit"],
                exitActive: classes["slide-active-exit"],
                exitDone: classes["slide-done-exit"]
              }}
            >
              <ColoredBox>Content-{i}</ColoredBox>
            </CSSTransition>
          ) : null
        )}
      </TransitionGroup>
```

## old answer

old answer before clarification from OP:
<strike>Its a bit unclear what you're actually trying to achieve.</strike>

#### why use transition group?

Usually a `<TransistionGroup />` is used to set the `in` property  on a `<Collapse/>`  automatically. For example when adding a bunch of items in a list.

You would not need to have the `<TransistionGroup />` if you just want to render 2 columns.
You can pass the `in` boolean manually.

#### Styling the collapse.

you can pass styling to the collapse wrapper and set any css you need.
IE:

```
       <Collapse
          in={isOn}
          orientation="horizontal"
          style={{ flex: "1", display: "inline-block" }}
        >
```

## Example

have a look at this [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-forked-6eqzs)

It has 2 examples:

- version 1 that just open/close the columns
- version 2 that adds columns and uses transitiongroup to expand them

I think version 1 is what you're really looking for:

```
const Example1 = () => {
  const [isOn, setIsOn] = React.useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOn((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={toggle}>
        {isOn ? "collapse" : "expand"}
      </Button>

      <Box display="flex">
        <Collapse
          in={isOn}
          orientation="horizontal"
          style={{ flex: "1", display: "inline-block" }}
        >
          <Box>Content-A</Box>
        </Collapse>
        <Collapse
          in={isOn}
          orientation="horizontal"
          style={{ flex: "1", display: "inline-block" }}
        >
          <Box>Content-B</Box>
        </Collapse>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I need the transition group because I want a specific transition to happen. Basically I have the page split in left (A) and right (B). On an event I want (A) to transition out the screen (to the left, hence horizontal). (B) should transition to the place where (A) was and a new element (C) comes in from the right and transitions to where (B) was. Imagine it is like a Sliding Queue. Then it is rinse and repeat (B out -> C goes to where B was -> D transitions in to where C was). The problem is that using Collapse horizontal it wont flex the remaining space.

Comment: Here is a demo from the docs https://codesandbox.io/s/5uyz7?file=/demo.js . Basically I want something similar, but 1.) horizontal and 2.) only with 2 items showing at a time. If a third item comes, the 1st one moves out and the 2nd one becomes the 1st one now (like a FIFO Queue). And finally 3.) The two items should split the page in Left and Right side with flex: 1

Comment: I've added a new answer, I think `Collapse` and `flex` are not meant to be used together,
You could create your own `Collapse`, by defining the transition yourself in a `CSStransition`. check the code sandbox for an example.

Comment: Oh this looks very promising. I tried to mess around a little bit real quick and if I make the Transitiongroup height: '100vh' so the 2 Boxes span over the whole page the transition becomes pretty choppy/stutters. But I will adjust and mess around more later on. This should hopefully work. I'll mark you answer as solution once I get it working.  Thank you.